# store data on basis of date and time - Reservation system

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, database-schema

I am making a restaurant table reservation project where a customer can book a particular table (according to where table is placed in restaurant).

What I thought -

A table bean(table's class) with attributes - id, isReserved(boolean) - to get which tables are not reserved yet. This bean class corresponds to a 'tables' relation in db. 'tables' will have 20 records(20 different tables with different locations).

Then there is a customer class which corresponds to customer table in db. Customer will be stored when he makes a reservation. Attributes - id, email, contact, reservedTable_id.

But now I think all this is useless because a customer books a table according to a date and time. Everytime he looks for a table on a different date, it should have 'isReserved' entry for that date. So, does that means I should limit the days for reservation(eg 10) and create 10  'tables' tables, 1 for each day. But still how will time be adjusted like for eg a table can be booked multiple times in a day.

I am really confused and I think I am missing something(or some concepts) or my approach to problem is not correct. I have googled this date and time  problem but I am not clear at all. If I am missing something, I am ready to read those concepts if someone guides me. Please help.

Comment: i think you should use 3 database tables, 1 - for tables, 2 - customer, 3 for the reservation. The 3rd table holds the table_id, customer_id, reservation date, and a particular hour within the reservation date.

Comment: @Leo Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some idea, hope it helps.
Create 3 Tables (Database Table):

1. Tables (Dinning Table)
2. Customer
3. Reservation

The 3rd table will hold the table_id, customer_id, reservation_date, reservation_hour columns.

Column Description:

- table_id         => PK of table 1
- customer_id      => PK of table 2
- reservation_date => date of reservation
- reservation_hour => specific time within the reservation date

Comment: So now I will keep only table_id attribute in tables(Dinning Table) table and whenever I want to query about a table, I will query it according to date and time from reservation table?

Comment: Yes, its like table 1 and 2 are your Master List / Setup Table while table 3 is for your transaction Transaction table.